Understanding Chasles' theorem
In a rigid body, let $p(t)=[x(t), y(t),z(t)]^T$ be a point on the rigid body, after rotation $R(t)$ and translation $T(t)$ from the initial position $p(0)$:
$p(t)=R(t)p(0)+T(t)$. (1)
According to Charles Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chasles%27_theorem_(kinematics)),
the Translation vector
$T(t)=(I_3-R(t))u+\theta \times pitch \times \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$, (2)
where $u$ is an arbitrary point on the screw axis, $\theta$ is the angle of rotation, R(t) is the rotation matrix.
Let $\dot{R}(t)=\Omega(t)$
then $\dot{T}(t)=-\Omega(t)u+\dot{\theta}\times pitch \times \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$ (3)
thus
$\dot{p}(t)=\Omega(t)p(0)+\dot{T}(t)=\Omega(t)(p(0)-u)+ \dot{\theta}\times pitch \times \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$ (4)
but the correct answer should be
$\dot{p}(t)=\Omega(t)(p(t)-u)+ \dot{\theta}\times pitch \times \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$  (5)
where $p(t)-u$ is the relative position of the point w.r.t. $u$ on screw axis,
so that $\dot{p}(t) = \Omega(t) p(t) + v$  (6)
where $v=-\Omega(t)u+\dot{\theta}\times pitch\times \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$ (7)
where did I make a mistake so that $p(t)$ becomes $p(0)$ in my derivation in eqn(4) ?

$~\dot R=\Omega^x,R~$ where $~\Omega^x~$ is skey symmetric matrix

If
the Translation vector is
$$T=(I_3-R)u+\theta ~ pitch~ \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$$
thus the time derivative is
$$\dot T=-\dot R\,u+\dot \theta ~ pitch~ \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$$
with
$~\dot R=\omega^x\,R~$
$$\dot T=-(\omega\times R\,u) +\dot \theta ~ pitch~ \frac{\hat{v}}{2\pi}$$
